# Where can one find the tractate Middoth?

Tags: mishna, english, masechet-midot

Where can one find the tractate Middoth in English? Are there things to consider in regard to the translation? Are there books that explain it?

Comment: online at https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Middot.1?lang=bi or ArtScroll's edition with commentary http://artscroll.com/Books/9781422600177.html

Comment: you tagged gemara but this is a tractate of the mishna without corresponding gemara - maybe that is why you didn't find it

Comment: Here's halakhah.com's pdf  version:  http://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Middoth.pdf     I don't know much about the translation, but the forewords and introductions(main page at http://halakhah.com/) are by Rabbis Epstein and J. Hertz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Blackman translation starting on page 250 [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9672&st=middoth&pgnum=250&hilite=).

I have always regarded this translation as reliable.

There is also the [Mishnah Behirah: Middot](http://seforimcenter.com/Mishnah-Behirah/Mishnah-Behirah-Middot__p-472-5847.aspx) around $21. You can “look inside” to see [sample illustrations](http://seforimcenter.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=5847.gif).